# JSON Product viewer in PHP

Tags: php, json, curl

I need to create a website that pulls data from a JSON API. The information is a product catalogue that contains the following array in JSON format.

```
[{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Product Name",
    "Description": "Lorem Ipsum"
},
{
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Product no 2"
    "Description": "Lorem Ipsum"
}]
```

I've already successfully used curl to get the JSON and json_decode the data.

I need my website to have an index page that contains list of products (with just the name) that links to a more detail page that contains the description.

I need help on how to best approach this.

Thanks

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what the problem is?  You need to know how to access an object property?  Echo strings into HTML?  Handle query-string parameters?  Dynamically query a RESTful service?  `echo '<a href="index.php?product=', urlencode($product->id), '">cool stuff</a>`

Comment: Basically I need to make a product catalogue and the main page should list all the available products. If the end user wants to find out more about the product they can click on the product to see more info. In the typical php+mysql, I could send the id through query string and use WHERE id = 1 when selecting a product. In this case my question is how do I achieve the same with an array created using json_decode? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you need `index.php` do both jobs: act as a catalog *and* as a product presentation page.

The first thing you need to do is check if `$_GET['product']` is set, in which case you should present the product, otherwise render a catalogue.

You could start by doing the following:

```
$cat=json_decode($retrieved_json);
if(!isset($_GET['product']))
  {
  // act as a catalog
  $n=count($cat);
  echo "<h3><em>$n</em> products:</h3>\n<ul>";
  foreach($cat as $product) 
    echo "<li><a href='?product={$product->id}'>{$product->name}</a></li>\n";
  echo "</ul>";
  }
else
  {
  $product=$product_by_id($_GET['roduct']);
  if($product)
    {
    // act as a product presentation, if the id exists
    echo "<h3>{$product->name}</h3>\n";
    echo "<p>{$product->Description}</p>\n";
    echo "<p><em>Product id:<strong>{$product->id}</strong></em></p>\n";
    }
  else
    // display an error for non-existent ids
    echo "<h2>No product with id={$_GET['roduct']} was found!</h2>";
  }

// returns $cat's entry for the product $id
// or false if not found
function product_by_id($id)
  {
  global $cat;
  for($i=0;($i<count($cat)))&&($cat[$i]->id!=$id));$i++) {}
  return ($i<count($cat)?$cat[$i]:false);
  }
```

Comment: I prefer not to store the data to the database. That's why I prefer to use curl to access the data and perhaps cache it somewhere.

Comment: Is it safe to assume that the JSON you are receiving contains an array with multiple products and not just one? _(maybe it would be appropriate to edit your question to reflect that)_ If so, I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: Well, I've edited my answer anyway, since it would cover both cases ;).

Comment: Thanks geomagas. Yes it contains array of products. I will try your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting. Most times you would use AJAX to get JSON data back from the server, I suppose you could do the same using curl. If you are able to assign the json string to a variable, you can simply json_decode it to create a php object.

Example:

```
$curl_response = getCurlData(); // Pretend this is your CURL retrieving function
$obj = json_decode($curl_response);
```

Then you can loop over the values in that object as you would any object, as such:

```
foreach ($obj as $data) {
    echo '<a href="index.php?product=' . $data->id . '">Product</a>';
}
```

Comment: He already did that part, as mentioned in his question.

Comment: Noted. And updated the last little detail.